# How to change the route value of a action link and keep the id value we need in mvc c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, routes, html.actionlink

here is my problem.I have a `html action link` for that I have given an `id`.(because when user clicks on it I want to get that `id` value from the controller.it works fine)

this is my html action link.

```
<div class="col-md-6 btn btn-default">
    @Html.ActionLink("MORE DETAILS", "Details", new { @did = @items.cruise_id })
</div>
```

this is my controller,where I get the id value.

```
public ActionResult Details(string did)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(did);
    return View();
}
```

then, when user clicks on link the `path/url' in browser address bar looks like this

```
http://localhost:3199/Home/Details?did=MA20160821BRIBRI
```

what I'm asking ,

- Is it possible to change this url or path as we need, but should have the `id`(in this case `did`),to get that value in controller using c# or jquery.
- if it is possible, when user copy,paste and run the url, it should work fine line the same.
- The main idea is ,I want this `did`,but should not show in the url(path), and when someone copy/paste it should work fine.

hope your help with this.

Comment: I doubt that is possible. However consider encrypting the value before sending.

Comment: Change it to what exactly? Can you provide an example?

Comment: in this case I get `http://localhost:3199/Home/Details?did=MA20160821BRIBRI` but can I display it like this in `http://localhost:3199/Home/Details/europe/italy/rome/test40`. but I want the `did` value in the controller.

Comment: @bill since it's not in the URL there's nothing passing the ID to the server... unless you put it in a cookie (and then linking won't work). I wouldn't recommend it though. This is what URLs are for.

Comment: The other option - if it's this *specific* ID and not IDs in general - is to create a rewrite rule. But you'd have to create a rewrite rule for every URL you want to map, individually.

Comment: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite